# Adding to a ColdFusion classpath running on an instanced JRun server

Tags: service, coldfusion, web, classpath, jrun

I'm having some trouble getting my ColdFusion server classpath to recognize my custom Java jars.  The classpath is not reading my jvm.config file correctly (I assume out of my JRun server which is where the CF instance is running out of, it's a production server with multiple sites attached).  I have been banging my head against the wall for hours on this.  All the other sites I have run perfectly with these jar files.  One of them is basically a clone of this one, but for some reason this one won't recognize just this one part.  The rest of the site works fine but when it tries to access this jar (it's an image resizer) it cannot find it and when I looked in the CF admin the classpath does not show the path (at all) for the java directory like all the other sites.

There also isn't a service associated with this site (well, there is a running service that appears on the JRun manager, but not in the services listing in windows).  When I added one manually and attempted to start it, it said it was already running.  I've restarted the ColdFusion server but to no avail.  Should I restart the JRun server? (it will take down production sites)  What can I do here to get this piece working?

UPDATE: 9 October 2008
Ok, in order to remove the crappy old services that were sticking and not working I had to reboot the server, even manual removal didn't work.  So now I have a good server instance of ColdFusion running BUT the Java custom classes are still not being read into the CF instance.  I think I have to write a custom jvm.config file for that ColdFusion server instance, my question now is, do I have to restart JRun or can I just do that server instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered my own question eventually, here it is:

In console, you have to INSTALL the service manually with the following line:

jrunsvc -install jrun_server service-name service-display service-description -config custom_jvm.config

"jrun_server" is actually the instance you are installing on.  So if it's say production_02, that's the name of the jrun instance you install to.  The service name, display and description are all fluff that you can fill in yourself.  There are many config files to find on the internet as well if you need help writing your own.